# Is there any ways to change dart devtools "host" in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can do it in command-line like this.
"dart devtools **--host='host'**"
How to do it in VSCode?
I know how to change 'port'. **I want to change 'host', like "0.0.0.0:9100"**